# BigQuery - Structure, order of calculations and multiple With Clauses Question

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm new to BigQuery and SQL so I'm trying understand how to make a good structure for a large query.

I need to perform calculations where the result is not immediately written to the output table, I need to do further calculations of previous calculations and I would like to easily select which columns are written to the output table.

So far I have a structure below:

```
WITH
  CTE AS (
  SELECT
    difficult_to_understand_name as understandable_name,
    difficult_to_understand_name1 as understandable_name1,
    difficult_to_understand_name2 as understandable_name2,
    difficult_to_understand_name3 as understandable_name3
    
  FROM
    'table1'),
    
    cte2 as (
      select 
      understandable_name2
  CASE when understandable_name2 in ('pass') THEN 'Successful' else 'Failed'end as Successful_Failed
  from
  cte)

SELECT
   understandable_name
     as understandable_name1
     understandable_name2
     understandable_name3
     Successful_Failed
FROM
  CTE
```

Where CTE imports columns and renames them, CTE2 does some calculations and the columns are written to an output table via the Select statement.

This code obviously will not work as all the columns are not present in CTE - is there a standard way of doing this.

I see 2 options 1- is to  select every column from CTE in CTE2 (and if present in subsequent CTE3,4,5 sections) but this seems a bit messy and longwinded
option 2 - is to join the individual tables on a unique ID which seems neater but I assume is computationally expensive?

Comment: The idea of CTE is to use the latest query. So `cte2 as (select *, CASE  .... end as Successful_as Failed  from cte)`. Then use in your final query `FROM CTE2`.